# How to add "extension" to native mail client on iOS?

Tags: ios, email, native

I read an article last week that explains that Symantec is about to publish an application that will be an extension of the iOS native mail client (here is the ref.: http://goo.gl/xsIiC).

The relevant sentence from that article:

> that works as an extension to the Apple iOS mail client to encrypt and
>   decrypt documents.

My question is : how is that possible on an non jailbroken iPhone ?
The only thing we can do on the iOS native mailer (if I'm not wrong) is to prepare an email (with body, attachment, ...) and to associate an app to a file extension that can be received from the mailer.

Do you have any idea on what they are talking about ? Is it only commercial stuff or you think there's a way for them to do such an extension?

Thank you

Comment: It's probably a specific file type that will be able to be opened by the app. Or it's a hoax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Symantec is a pretty big company, and not too far from Apple's campus.  The vice presidents and/or executives probably even golf together.

In any event, Symantec has access to private API's or resources that regular peon developers like you or I would not have access to.  And either Symantec will release an app via the App Store (that Apple's reviewers will automatically approve and bless), or the extensions will be incorporated and included in a future version of iOS.

If you want extended functionality for Apple Mail, then file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com and if enough developers ask for it, Apple is more likely to make public the API that Symantec is using to extend Mail.app's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS: Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1).

> If your app is capable of opening specific types of files, you should
>   register that support with the system. This allows other apps, through
>   the iOS document interaction technology, to offer the user the option
>   to hand off those files to your app.
>
> To declare its support for file types, your app must include the
>   CFBundleDocumentTypes key in its Info.plistproperty list file. (See
>   “Core Foundation Keys”.) The system adds this information to a
>   registry that other apps can access through a document interaction
>   controller.

So if you provide your document types in your Info.plist, other apps that recognize that document type should list your app in their open in choices. Probably this is what Symantec is targeting. There could be some file types which we try to open in mail app can launch Symantec's app or something similar to that. And they might be calling that app as an extension to mail app.